# How to check for Facebook account support in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode6

In my Facebook model class, I have a function to check whether the user's iOS supports Facebook account management:

```
+ (BOOL)canUseExternalNetwork
{
    return &ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook != nil;
}
```

Starting in Xcode 6.3, the compiler gives an error saying:

> Comparison of address ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook not equal to
>   null pointer is always true

First of all, I don't understand why an undefined constant on an old iOS would resolve to an address greater than 0. More importantly, I would like to fix this problem without hacks:

- I don't want to change the compiler settings to turn off this warning. All that will do is make my code run, but not run correctly.
- I don't want to use an iOS version check. Doing so may break in the future when Facebook is no longer supported. I think Facebook has already stopped using native login support with their new Graph API 2.0. The new SDK no longer uses an OS provided popup for login. Rather, it jumps to the Facebook app.
- A generic solution that works for any kind of constant would be nice. Although I only need to solve it for Facebook (and Twitter) for now, I'd still like to learn how to handle similar situations in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This has all the hallmarks of a slight misfeature (also known as a bug) in the compiler that it doesn't properly assess `-weak_framework` when using symbols defined in framework headers as being weakly linked, and as such considers the code a no-op.

This means that the optimizer is happily able to **remove** the if check from the code - and it does do that when I use a simple test piece of code.

```
#import <Accounts/ACAccountType.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (&ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook != NULL)
        NSLog(@"Hello\n");
    return (0);
}
```

This code compiled with:

```
$ clang -weak_framework Accounts -framework Foundation weak.m
weak.m:8:10: warning: comparison of address of 'ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (&ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook != NULL)
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

When examined, shows that the `ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook` symbol is not even referenced in the code:

```
$ nm -m a.out
                 (undefined) external _NSLog (from Foundation)
                 (undefined) external ___CFConstantStringClassReference (from CoreFoundation)
0000000100000000 (__TEXT,__text) [referenced dynamically] external __mh_execute_header
0000000100000f40 (__TEXT,__text) external _main
                 (undefined) external dyld_stub_binder (from libSystem)
```

i.e. the optimizer removed it entirely. You can use `otool -tv a.out` to examine the resultant code, and you'll see that the if test is completely skipped.

Hopefully it will be fixed in a future release of the compiler, however you can work around the problem for the time being.

In order to get the compiler to consider the symbol to be weak, it needs to explicitly be marked as a [*weak import*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-107262-CJBJAEID), which means that it needs to look something like:

```
extern NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook __attribute__((weak_import));
```

This means that code that looks like:

```
if (&ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Have Facebook");
}
```

will then work properly. If we add a line like that to the start of the sample code, and compile it we see that it compiles without issue, and as well, that the symbol is present in the output of `nm -m a.out`, and the if test is present in the resulting output from `otool -tv a.out`.